# Unable to access H2 console in spring-boot in reactive mode with Netty server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, h2, reactor-netty

I am building a new Spring boot application with h2 db in WebFlux stack along with Netflix DGS. I want to access h2 DB console. I have used following configuration but I am not able to access my H2 DB console with this config. Though db is spinning up and during application startup I can able to load the data into DB programattically.

```
gradle file
------------
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation(platform("com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-platform-dependencies:5.5.5"))
    implementation 'com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-webflux-starter:5.5.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

application.yml
---------------
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local
  graphql:
    graphiql:
      #http://localhost:8080/graphiql
      enabled: true
  datasource:
     url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=PostgreSQL
     driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
     username: sa
     password: password
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
```

If I try to access H2 console url getting 404 error.

this is my URL - http://localhost:8080/h2-console/

Answer (score 1):

`H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration`  is not available for spring webflux. You may have to configure the H2 configuration manually by defining a Server for your H2 Console. You can create a webserver in your code and then try to work with that.